# Wrong result returned by mysql for simple select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very confused to see the result I am getting from mysql for the below query.

```
SELECT id, email, full_name FROM user WHERE `email` = 0 AND `password` = 0
```

It is giving me this result

[image]

How could that be possible? When I enclose those zeros in quotes, it gives no result. What is the reason?

Btw, the row returned is there in the database, but it definitely doesn't have 0 in email or password.

The column types are : `email` is `VARCHAR(100)` and password is `CHAR(32)`

Comment: enclose with single quote `'` its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field really has `e`, `m`, `a`, etc... in it? Since you're comparing `string = integer`, mysql will convert the string to an integer:

```
(int)'email' -> 0
```

and of course

```
0 = 0 -> true
```

If your fields were (say) `9email`, then `(int)'9email' -> 9` and `0 = 9` would be false. Same for `'email' = '0'`. Those two strings are NOT equal, so the row would never match.